# Mongoose object schema: How do I declare schema in mongoosejs to be able to iterate an options field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

Currently the data in mogo via mongoose is as below. I want to be able to iterate options once I pull it out of mongo.
currently if I save this record to a variable “record". I would need to do record.options[0].option1.check, I want to avoid [0].
I want to be able to just iterate over an object and be able to do the following.
record.option1.choice1
record.option2.choice2

```
my schema is 
    var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    question_slug: String,
    options: []
});



    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5832609483bf491db3d8faa1"),
        "question" : “What is the capital of Illinois?",
        "question_slug" : “what-is-the-capital-of-illinois",
        "options" : [
                {
                        "option1" : {
                                "check" : "on",
                                "choice" : “Springfield"
                        },
                        "option2" : {
                                "check" : "",
                                "choice" : “Chicago"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the schema for `record.option1.choice1` and `record.option2.choice2` since `option1` and `option2` seems to be dynamic.

But you can avoid `[0]` for `record.options[0].option1.check` by defining `options` as `Object` in the `schema` instead of `array` as below.

Hence, you can iterate over the object `record.options` with `record.options.option1` and `record.options.option2` etc.

```
var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    question_slug: String,
    options: {
       type: Object
    }
});



{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5832609483bf491db3d8faa1"),
    "question" : “What is the capital of Illinois?",
    "question_slug" : “what-is-the-capital-of-illinois",
    "options" : {
                    "option1" : {
                            "check" : "on",
                            "choice" : “Springfield"
                    },
                    "option2" : {
                            "check" : "",
                            "choice" : “Chicago"
                    }
    },
    "__v" : 0
```

}

Comment: That worked, how do I accept the answer? Dont have enough rep to upvote.

Comment: Great:-) You have to click the tick icon to accept the answer. You can scroll up to top of the answer, there will be up and down arrows left to my answer. Or you can see number 0. Below the number 0, you can see a down arrow. If you bring the mouse cursor to the down arrow and a bit down again, you can see a tick icon which you have to click to accept the answer.